# Is there a way to send C++ Runtime Library Assertion Failed messages to the Console instead of a dialog box?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, terminal

I'm working on a very small C++ console application using only VSCode and the command line.  (I do not have access to the full Visual Studio on the machine I'm using.)

When an assertion occurs, I get a dialog like this:

[image]

Is there any way to make this debug information appear in the console, instead of the dialog box?

Comment: you can write your own assert that doesn't do that. but maybe you should not use assert at first place.

Answer (score 5):

Add this to main()

```
_CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE | _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG );
_CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDERR );
```

And take a look at the docs for [CrtSetReportMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetreportmode?view=msvc-170).